# Is there an open source alternative to Reuters Kondor+?

Tags: trading-systems

Basically, I'm looking for a system which have trading(in a demo account), book keeping, profit/loss and risk calculation capability across different asset classes such as bond, repo, equity, foreign exchange, derivatives etc.

Comment: open gamma or trade link?

Comment: Incidentally, anyone have a reliable link to a page about Kondor+ ? Reuters website keeps giving me 404s, even when following links in their own search results!

Comment: Reuters has sold Kondor+. It belongs now to Misys http://kondor.misys.com/.

Answer (score 3):

The ones I know are

- [Marketcetera](http://www.marketcetera.com/site/)
- [Merchant of venice (mov)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mov/)

But I found [this page](http://estefancivera.blogspot.com/2010/03/open-source-lkibrary-and-trading-system.html) with an interesting list on the internet.

Comment: VERY nice list you found! Thank you, it is comprehensive. (I know you! I am Demeter when I'm not here as Feral Oink.)

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGamma platform ([www.opengamma.com](http://www.opengamma.com)) is probably the most comprehensive trading and risk analytics offer in the open source world. It supports the interest rate, forex and equity products you mentioned. It contains also a strong quantitative finance library.

Comment: Marc, you need to point-out that you work for OpenGamma. Otherwise it's an undisclosed conflict of interest to post this.